# Auto generated Azure could-shell-storage account

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-account

I have Azure Pay-As-You-Go subscription account having Azure Storage general purpose V1 Service where I store files. I wondered yesterday, when I found another storage account with different location which I haven't created. For details screen shot is given: 
[image]

If you have any knowledge about it or faced same behavior on Azure Storage, please guide and share your experience as I want to know what it is for and why it has been created on different location as my other services are in different resource group on Notrh Europe Location.

Comment: You can take a look at the Activity Log to see who create the resources.

Comment: `When you use basic settings and select only a subscription, Cloud Shell creates three resources on your behalf in the supported region that's nearest to you`, the auto-generated storage account always named as `cs<uniqueGuid>`, read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/persisting-shell-storage#create-new-storage)

Comment: @NancyXiong..Please provide your comment as an answer.

Comment: Hi Sameer, please check if my edited reply could solve your question. If you have any concerns, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks @NancyXiong it is helpful and you have clarified it.

Answer (score 2):

> please guide and share your experience as I want to know what it is
>   for and why it has been created on different location as my other
>   services are in different resource group on Notrh Europe Location.

When you use Azure cloud shell, on the initial start, Cloud Shell prompts you to associate a new or existing file share to persist files across sessions.

When you use basic settings and select only a subscription, Cloud
Shell creates **three resources** on your behalf in the supported region
that's nearest to you. The auto-generated storage account always names `cs<uniqueGuid>`, read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/persisting-shell-storage#create-new-storage).

[image]

Also, Azure creates a disk image of your `$Home` directory to persist all contents within the directory. The disk image is saved in your specified file share as `acc_<User>.img` 
at `fileshare.storage.windows.net/fileshare/.cloudconsole/acc_<User>.img`, and it automatically syncs changes.

[image]

About the **region**, it depended on the region when you select the associated Azure storage account when initially start with Cloud shell. Associated Azure storage accounts must reside in the same region as the Cloud Shell machine that you're mounting them to. Its region is totally not related to your other Azure resource group. You also could run `clouddrive unmount` to re-select an associated storage account for the Azure file share.

To find your current region you may run `env` in Bash and locate the variable `ACC_LOCATION`. 
[image]